# Loading the result of a PHP script into a div from a link with JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have been trying to load the content of a link to a div element without reloading the page. I found this solution 'http://wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-7071545.htm' and have tried it but I couldn't get it to work.

What I am doing is exactly the same, but for some reason it doesn't work.

This is the Jquery part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateContainer( url ){
        dynamicCon = '#mainContent';    
        ObjTag = $( dynamicCon );
        ObjTag.load( url );
    }
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'a[rel="dynamicLoad"]' ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
            url = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
            updateContainer( url );
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the PHP bit I use to output the HTML:

```
echo '<li><a href = "/getPost.php?q='. $row['id'] .' " rel="dynamicLoad" >'. $row['title'] .'</a> </li> <br>';
```

But this sends me to the link instead of loading it into the div. The div I want the content to load into is called "mainContent". Now, I can't say I know JQuery but everything looks OK to me but obviously I am missing something.

UPDATE: I tried linking to a later library, restart the server, cleared the browser cache and changed the Javascript to:

```
        function updateContainer( url ){
            dynamicCon = '#mainContent';    
            ObjTag = $( dynamicCon );
            $("#mainContent").load(url)
        }
        $( document ).ready( function() {
            $( 'a[rel="dynamicLoad"]' ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
                url = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
                updateContainer( url );
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
```

Now, when I try to load a link the mainContent div becomes empty (certainly an improvement considering the situation)

UPDATE 2: I uploaded the thing on the net if you want to poke around. electricbrownie.net

Comment: TRY `$("#mainContent").load(url)`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to **load the content** of `getPost.php` (which I imagine is a complete article) **into** your `#mainContent` div, right? Your PHP code doesn't do that: it only outputs an `<li>` with a link to the content.

Comment: The part that gets the post is getPost.php. I output the HTML of the link with the code I wrote in the question. The getpost.php part is probably is okay since I was able to use an onclick event and change the content of the div with innerHTML.

Comment: Check firebug/developer console. Are you sure you have jquery in your `<script src="jquery.js"></script>? If you go directly to this link do you see any errors?

Comment: Almost exactly the same code works fine on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NDHQS/2/

Comment: no errors, I link to google for the library.

Comment: @CodeBunny looks like something wrong with the code which you didn't posted yet. As can you see it works on jsfiddle

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov please see the update. I can send the whole thing but getContent.php obviously works (as onclick with innerHTML works) and there are no other relevant parts of the code.

Comment: @CodeBunny it should work. obviously code is wrong somewhere. Can view page source in browser and post it here including div with id `mainContent` and with all javascript. If its not too big post here whole source. (not php source, just html as it seen in browser's view source)

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov I uploaded the thing on the net. here is the link http://electricbrownie.net/

Comment: @CodeBunny As i said in the answer - you still have trailing whitespace in your href attribute. That's why it doesn't work. see `<a href="/getPost.php?q=2 " rel="dynamicLoad">stuff happening</a>`. After `q=2` there is a space, remove it and it'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer is simple. In your generated urls remove trailing spaces and it will work :)

```
echo '<li><a href = "/getPost.php?q='. $row['id'] .'" rel="dynamicLoad" >'. $row['title'] .'</a> </li> <br>';
```

it was `<a href = "/getPost.php?q='. $row['id'] .' "` should be `<a href = "/getPost.php?q='. $row['id'] .'"`

Comment: thank you. I hate it when the problem is essentially a typo : )

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it is because the default functionality of the `<a>` element is to send you to the `href` attribute.  Just try this to see if it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'a[rel="dynamicLoad"]' ).each(function(index){
            $(this).click(function(){
                url = '/getPost.php?q='+$(this).attr('id');
                $('#mainContent').load(url);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
...
    echo '<li><a id="'.$row['id'].'" href = "#" rel="dynamicLoad" >'. $row['title'] .'</a> </li> <br>';
?>
```

Comment: OK i updated the javascript, still have the modified HTML, try that out.

Comment: by the way the id refers to the id of the article stored on the database it is not the id of the HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $( 'a[rel="dynamicLoad"]' ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
        var url = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
        $.get(url, function(data) {
            $('#mainContent').html( data);             
        }):
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: the code is in web server?

what apears in javascript console?